# React display percentage next to the number input or vice versa

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm writing a component with a total cost for the house. 
There is an input for the dollar downpayment and the percentage downpayment. When a user types a number I want to display the percentage in the place of the input and same if the person types the percentage.

Just to illustrate it would look like this:

Total cost: 200,000
Down payment: $0, Percentage: 0%

So we change the percentage to 5%, down payment automatically shows $10,000 - you get the idea.

I'm currently grabbing the value of the input like so:

```
handleStateChange = (e) => {
        const { target: { name, value } } = e
        this.setState({ [name]: value })
    }
```

Inside the input:

```
name="downPayment" value={ this.state.value } onChange={this.handleStateChange}
```

What is the best and efficient way to write a function eg. handlePercentageChange() that does this in both directions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
handleInputChange = (e) => {
  const { target: { name, value } } = e
  this.setState({ [name]: value })

  switch(name) {

    case 'downPaymentPercent' :
      const newAmount = value/100 * this.state.fullPrice // Assuming fullPrice set in state
      this.setState({ downPaymentAmount: newAmount })
      break
    case 'downPaymentAmount' :
      const newPercent = (value * 100) / this.state.fullPrice
      this.setState({ downPaymentPercent: newPercent })
      break
    default:
      break
  }
}


 // The 2 inputs
 name="downPaymentAmount" value={ this.state.downPaymentAmount } onChange={this.handleInputChange}
 name="downPaymentPercent" value={ this.state.downPaymentPercent } onChange={this.handleInputChange}
```

Comment: this doesn't calculate the percentage or dollar amount based on the house cost input though?

Comment: Updated. I am assuming that you have the house price set in state or on the class. Hope that works